# Setting up a Nginx config file with php-fpm results in 502 bad gateway

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, nginx

I'm following [a guide to set up a ubuntu VPS](http://www.wpmayor.com/step-by-step/ultimate-guide-setting-wordpress-vps-part-2/) as a nginx webserver for wordpress.

When setting up Nginx and PHP the guide I'm using suggests I uncomment this line in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Having done this, although the server's welcome page works, I get a 502 bad gateway error when going to a php file I created (containing phpinfo)

However, when I uncomment this line instead:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

The php file appears to load successfully

Can anyone explain what each line does and why the one I used works but the one in the tutorial does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;" nginx tries to connect to fastcgi using a TCP connection on port 9000 in order to "interpret" your php files. When using "fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;" it tries to bind to a socket file which does not use the network stack. It is a manner of preference, a TCP socket is usually easier to setup due to permissions issues. You can't connect at the same time to a TCP port and a SOCKET.

Comment: OK, so any suggestions on how I can get the TCP method to work? Or at least to work out why it's broken...

Comment: First try to see if php5-fpm listens on TCP port 9000. You find this out with: `$ sudo netstat -pant | grep 9000`. If it does not listen then you should check if it's started and if it's started and still not listening, look into the config file of php5-fpm. Or just use the socket option.

Comment: The config file should look something like this: `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`
`;listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock` so listen 127.... is active and listen /var/run is commented.

Comment: OK great thanks. Sorry I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to sysadmining. Will give it a try when I get a chance. But basically there is no problem with the socket option?

Comment: If it functions, then there is no problem. Some say it is even faster through sockets because it bypasses the network stack.

Comment: Great, well it functions so I'll probably leave it be. Thanks for the teachings...